# Yii2 PageCache invalidation

Tags: caching, yii2, invalidation

Is there any possibility to invalidate or delete PageCache for a particular action.

Consider this:

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'pageCache' => [
                'class' => PageCache::className(),
                'duration' => Yii::$app->params['cacheTime'], // seconds
                'variations' => [
                    Yii::$app->language,
                    Yii::$app->request->get('id'), 
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actionIndex( $id )
    {
       // action code 
    }
}
```

And now I want to remove/invalidate cache for

> action en/site/index?id=1

Currently I am thinking to write some code in a console app but do not know how to achieve this.

**EDIT1**: I try to rebuild-invalidate cache manually for a specific action. The code can't relay on 'dependency' because it is almost impossible to implement for that action.

**EDIT2**: The task is to rebuild cache only for the specific action (page) leave other cache intact.

Comment: if i understand correctly you want to disable the caching for a specific action ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I want to rebuild cache for a specific action

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`TagDependency`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-caching-tagdependency) for more granular invalidation:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'pageCache' => [
            'class' => PageCache::className(),
            'duration' => Yii::$app->params['cacheTime'], // seconds
            'variations' => [
                Yii::$app->language,
                Yii::$app->request->get('id'), 
            ],
            'dependency' => new \yii\caching\TagDependency([
                'tags' => [
                    Yii::$app->requestedRoute,
                    Yii::$app->request->get('id'),
                ],
            ]),
        ],
    ];
}
```

To invalidate cache:

```
TagDependency::invalidate(Yii::$app->cache, [
    'site/index', // route of action 
    123, // ID of page
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone else needs ...
Yii2 does not provide a native function to invalidate the cache of a specific page, however there is the delete function of the cache component. It would however be necessary to know the generated key for the requested page but the function that generates this key is protected (calculateCacheKey ()). In this way, the best way would be to create your own class extending \yii\filters\PageCache.

```
    'pageCache' => function () {
        return new class extends \yii\filters\PageCache{
            public function init(){
                parent::init();
                $this->except = ['index'];
                $this->duration = Yii::$app->params['cacheTime'], // seconds;
                $this->variations = [
                   Yii::$app->language,
                   Yii::$app->request->get('id'), 
                ];
                if(Yii::$app->request->get('IC') == 1)
                    Yii::$app->cache->delete($this->calculateCacheKey());
            }
            public function beforeCacheResponse(){                  
                return Yii::$app->request->get('IC') != 1;
            }
        };
    },
```

In the provided code, for simplicity, I am using an anonymous class (PHP 7). 
Instead you can create your class as you wish and inform its path as the 'class' parameter, as seen in the configuration displayed in the question.

Note that I am using a simple logic to invalidate the cache, checking if there is a GET parameter IC == 1, you can use whatever logic you want.

If after invalidating the cache you do not want a new cache to be created, simply return false in beforeCacheResponse, it is from \yii\filters\PageCache.

Answer (score 0):

You can invalidate the cache by using dependencies

```
'pageCache' => [
        ...
        'dependency' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\DbDependency',
            'sql' => 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post',
        ],
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-pagecache.html#$dependency-detail

Comment: I know about this feature but there is not any dependency that can be used

Comment: You could set a dependency value that is only used for clearing the cache but that's a bit hacky. If you can get the [calculated key](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/filters/PageCache.php#L295), you should be able to use the [data caching](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-data.html) methods e.g., `delete()` to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, currently thinking in this way but I still hope that there is a simple solution for this task. In my opinion it is a common task to remove cache for a certain page-action manually.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to disable caching only for a specific action and according to the [**`DOCS`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-pagecache.html) you can use the following options to explicitly identify which action IDs to apply the cache filter OR which action IDs it should not.

`$except`   array   List of action IDs that this filter should not apply to.    yii\base\ActionFilter

`$only` array   List of action IDs that this filter should apply to.

The following should work for you

```
return [
        'pageCache' => [
            'class' => PageCache::className(),
            'except'=>['index']
            'duration' => Yii::$app->params['cacheTime'], // seconds
            'variations' => [
                Yii::$app->language,
                Yii::$app->request->get('id'), 
            ],
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: I try to rebuild-invalidate cache manually for a specific action. The code can't relay on 'dependency' because it is almost impossible to implement for that action.

Comment: well, the documentation says that **When you need to invalidate all the stored cache data, you can call [`yii\caching\Cache::flush()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-data.html#cache-flushing).** and you can use console commands flush or to see stored cache. @sim

Comment: This command will flush ALL cached data but it is not effective if the task is to invalidated-rebuild cache only for one action.

Comment: if you check the link i provided it provides console commands to list all the caches that are used dont they help in your case ? @sim

Comment: No, the command "yii cache" lists cache components which are configured in config file. Cache component's config represents a whole storage not a particular action or page.